Custom web component Stack view issue with NX & Angular 17
We are using NX with Angular 17 in our monorepo, which includes custom web components built with Angular. One of these components is a Stack View, which acts as an overlay at the top of the screen (implemented using a singleton service within the web component package).
This setup worked perfectly in Angular 16, but after upgrading to Angular 17, the component no longer renders, and there are no console errors or logs to help diagnose the issue. We also tested it with Angular 18, but the problem persists (NX version 19.5.6). Has anyone else encountered this issue or can provide guidance on resolving it?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated
